# How to send data from BLE MCU to the Windows?

Tags: communication, bluetooth, bluetooth-low-energy, microsoft-windows

I have one nRF based 52840 device, which I am using to send the data by using BLE technology, my laptop has windows 10 and Bluetooth 4.0, which can detect the BLE but it cannot even connect to it.
I am very new to this, and I am exploring the internet for days but didn't understand anything.
Please guide me on a path that I can follow so that I can make an app that can display the values from BLE device.
Many people are recommending using Microsoft BLE explorer App source code, I have tried that too it can also just shows the device but can not connect to it.

Comment: Is your app running on the nRF52840 actually allowing connections? Some apps just advertise data. There are plenty of apps for Android or iOS to scan for BLE devices, connect to them, etc, what do those say?

Comment: @jcaron My firmware from my nRF was corrupt hence it was just showing and not connecting, but now it is connecting, and I am using Windows BLE sample to show the parameters of that device too, now I just have to configure that app according to my needs.